# Turning JSON object value into decimal number after calculation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have pulled in some data for my app via an external JSON url which has resulted in the value I require, which is currently a string that is "0.00"

result.data.app_payamount = "0.00"

When I convert my strings into numbers and calculate a value I am only being returned a part number and not a full decimal value used for currency.
[image]
[image]

How can I edit this code so the payamount displays a full decimal number suitable for currency?

```
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var results = response.data;
        var urlStart = 'http://exmaple.com/api';
        if (response.config.url.startsWith(urlStart)) {
            angular.forEach(results, function(result, key) { 
                result.data.CardFee = 2.00;
                result.data.app_bookingfee = result.data.CardFee;
                result.data.app_payamount = +result.data.app_subtotal + +result.data.app_handling + -result.data.app_discount + +result.data.app_adjustment + +result.data.app_bookingfee;
            });
```

Comment: Use `toFixed` e.g. `var newNum = oldNum.toFixed(2);`

Comment: I think doing e.g. `+result.data.app_subtotal` converts to an integer not a floating number, which is what you want if you need decimals. 

So you may need to use `parseFloat(+result.data.app_subtotal)` or similar when you're converting from the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Number.toFixed() here.

```
        var deferred = $q.defer();
    var results = response.data;
    var urlStart = 'http://exmaple.com/api';
    if (response.config.url.startsWith(urlStart)) {
        angular.forEach(results, function(result, key) { 
            result.data.CardFee = 2.00;
            result.data.app_bookingfee = result.data.CardFee;
            result.data.app_payamount = +result.data.app_subtotal + +result.data.app_handling + -result.data.app_discount + +result.data.app_adjustment + +result.data.app_bookingfee;
            result.data.app_payamount = result.data.app_payamount.toFixed(2);
        });
```

Comment: oops, I'm late to the party. Well, there you have it. The answer is a unanimous `number.toFixed(2)`!

Comment: These calculations above are made within a factory in AngularJS in app.js. When I try and access them from another function in my controller it is pulling the original value for payamount. Is there a way I can make result.data.app_payamount.toFixed(2); available globally within the code you have published.

Comment: You can put the final value in the `$window` object, but that's bad practice. Feel free to ask another question about this, since it is not directly related to your original question, and may need you to show some more code.

Comment: Thanks for your help kennasoft, spun a new question for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126650/make-a-factory-js-variable-available-globally-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

In js, you can specify the number of digits like this:

```
n = n.toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `number.toFixed(2)`:

```
var n = 2;
var nStringInteger = n.toFixed(0);    // "2"
var nString1Decimal = n.toFixed(1);   // "2.0"
var nString2Decimal = n.toFixed(2);   // "2.00"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseFloat` and `toFixed`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to parse different strings.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var a = parseFloat("10.3265");
    var b = parseFloat("10.00");
    var c = parseFloat("10.33");
    var n = a + b + c;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = n.toFixed(2);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following currency directive to apply decimal places.

```
app.directive('currency', function ($filter, $locale) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            min: '=min',
            max: '=max',
            ngRequired: '=ngRequired'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

            function clearValue(value) {
                value = String(value);
                var dSeparator = $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.DECIMAL_SEP;
                var clear = value.match(/[\+\-0-9\.]/g);
                clear = clear ? clear.join("") : 0;
                return clear;
            }

            ngModel.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
                cVal = clearValue(viewValue);
                return parseFloat(cVal);
            });

            element.on("blur", function () {
                if (isNaN(ngModel.$modelValue)) {
                    ngModel.$modelValue = 0;
                    element.val($filter('currency')(clearValue(ngModel.$modelValue)));
                }
                else {
                    element.val($filter('currency')(ngModel.$modelValue));
                }
            });


            ngModel.$formatters.unshift(function (value) {
                return $filter('currency')(value);
            });

            scope.$watch(function () {
                return ngModel.$modelValue
            }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                runValidations(newValue)
            })

            function runValidations(cVal) {
                if (!scope.ngRequired && isNaN(cVal)) {
                    return
                }
                if (scope.min) {
                    var min = parseFloat(scope.min)
                    ngModel.$setValidity('min', cVal >= min)
                }
                if (scope.max) {
                    var max = parseFloat(scope.max)
                    ngModel.$setValidity('max', cVal <= max)
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```