# Make a factory JS variable available globally in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, global-variables

I have a variable created within a factory that I wish to use within another function in my controllers in AngularJS.

How can I make a variable from a factory available to my ListController onPay function?

I wish to use the new calculated value for

**result.data.bkor_payamount = result.data.bkor_payamount.toFixed(2);** (from the factory)

on

**myItem['unitPrice'] = result.data.bkor_payamount;** (onPay function in ListController)

*For example I can use this code below and it will pass the original value done before my http interceptor code that calculates the new amount.
myItem['unitPrice'] = order.data.bkor_payamount;*

**Just need to make the new value from result.data.bkor_payamount; available to use in my List_Controller**

I have tried making a new variable that i read would create a global variable but this doesn't seem to have worked within the app. At the moment it still calls the original value gathered from the JSON url rather than my calculation.

```
// Ionic Starter App

        // angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
        // 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
        // the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
        angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova'])

        .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
          $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {



            if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
              // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
              // for form inputs)
              cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

              // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
              // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
              // a much nicer keyboard experience.
              cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
            }
            if(window.StatusBar) {
              StatusBar.styleDefault();
            }
          });
        })

        .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

          $stateProvider
            .state('tabs', {
              url: '/tab',
              cache: false,
              abstract: true,
              templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
            })
            .state('tabs.home', {
              url: '/home',
              cache: false,
              views: {
                'home-tab' : {
                 templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
                }
              }
            })
            .state('tabs.list', {
              url: '/list',
              cache: false,
              views: {
                'list-tab' : {
                 templateUrl: 'templates/list.html',
                 controller: 'ListController'
                }
              }
            })

              // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
              $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/home');

        })

        .factory('httpInterceptor', function($q, $rootScope, $window) {
            var httpInterceptor = {
                response: function(response) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    var results = response.data;
                    var urlStart = 'http://example.com/';
                    if (response.config.url.startsWith(urlStart)) {
                        angular.forEach(results, function(result, key) { 
                            result.data.estCardFee = 2.00;
                            result.data.bkor_bookingfee = result.data.estCardFee;
                            result.data.bkor_payamount = +result.data.bkor_subtotal + +result.data.bkor_handling + -result.data.bkor_discount + +result.data.bkor_adjustment + +result.data.bkor_bookingfee;
                            result.data.bkor_payamount = result.data.bkor_payamount.toFixed(2);
                            result.data.bkor_paypalamount = result.data.bkor_payamount;
                        });
                    }
                    deferred.resolve(response);
                    return deferred.promise;
                }
            };
            return httpInterceptor;
        })
        .config(function($httpProvider) { 
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor'); 
        })

        .controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state','$stateParams', '$window', '$location', '$ionicPopup', function($scope, $http, $state, $stateParams, $cordovaBluetoothSerial, $window, $location, $ionicPopup) {

                  $scope.query = '';

                  $scope.getOrders= function(query){

                         $http.get('http://example.com/' + query).success(function(data) {
                          $scope.orders = data;
                          console.log($scope.query);
                          console.log(data);
                          console.log($scope.orders);

                         })
                  }

                //$scope.orders = [];

                 function onPay(order) {
                 var itemsArr = [];
                 var invoice = {};
                 var myItems = {};
                 var myItem = {};

                 myItem['unitPrice'] = result.data.bkor_paypalamount;
                 myItem['taxRate'] = '0.0';
                 myItem['taxName'] = 'Tax';
                 itemsArr.push(myItem);
                 myItems['item'] = itemsArr;

                 invoice['itemList'] = myItems;
                 invoice['paymentTerms'] = 'DueOnReceipt';
                 invoice['currencyCode'] = 'GBP';
                 invoice['discountPercent'] = '0';

                 var returnUrl = "http://example.com/";
                 var retUrl = encodeURIComponent(returnUrl + "?{result}?Type={Type}&InvoiceId={InvoiceId}&Tip={Tip}&Email={Email}&TxId={TxId}");
                 var pphereUrl = "paypalhere://takePayment/v2?returnUrl=" + retUrl;
                 pphereUrl = pphereUrl + "&accepted=cash,card,paypal";
                 pphereUrl = pphereUrl + "&step=choosePayment";
                 pphereUrl = pphereUrl + '&invoice=' + escape(JSON.stringify(invoice));
                 console.log(pphereUrl);

                 return pphereUrl;

                 }


                $scope.pay = function (order) {
                $scope.showButton = true;
                var url = onPay(order);
                window.open(url, "_system");
                }

        }]);
```

Comment: Is your issue got resolved?. If not , could you please explain the logic implemented in interceptor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little busy now, but I think you may want to put back the results in the data field of your resolve object in your `httpInterceptor` factory. And I changed the references to `result` in your `forEach()` to `results[key]` to be sure it modifies the original array (Hope this is an array?)

```
       .factory('httpInterceptor', function($q, $rootScope, $window) {
        var httpInterceptor = {
            response: function(response) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var results = response.data;
                var urlStart = 'http://example.com/';
                if (response.config.url.startsWith(urlStart)) {
                    angular.forEach(results, function(result, key) { 
                        results[key].data.estCardFee = 2.00;
                        results[key].data.bkor_bookingfee = results[key].data.estCardFee;
                        results[key].data.bkor_payamount = results[key].data.bkor_subtotal + results[key].data.bkor_handling - results[key].data.bkor_discount + results[key].data.bkor_adjustment + results[key].data.bkor_bookingfee;
                        results[key].data.bkor_payamount = parseFloat(results[key].data.bkor_payamount).toFixed(2);
                        results[key].data.bkor_paypalamount = results[key].data.bkor_payamount;
                    });
                }
                response.data = results;  //put the modified items back in the response
                deferred.resolve(response);
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        };
        return httpInterceptor;
    })
```

Comment: Hope this resolves your problem. If it doesn't, I will take another look when I'm less busy.

Comment: Got a bounty on this question if you are interested, currently getting ```results[key].data.bkor_payamount.toFixed is not a function``` within the console using your code above

Comment: If that doesn't fix it, do you mind sharing a sample `response` JSON?

Comment: I think it is the ```myItem['unitPrice'] = result.data.bkor_paypalamount;``` causing the error. If I add a value (eg"22") or comment this line out it works but obviously doesn't send the updated variable I require. An example of the successful JSON output is http://i.imgur.com/nwnwbeM.png

Comment: I don't see where the variable `result` is coming from in this controller... can you explain what you expect to happen here?

Comment: Hey, I was just awarded your bounty. Did you manage to figure it out finally?

Answer (score 0):

Angular services are singletons. So you could store the results in a property on an instance of a service and inject it into which ever controllers require the data

If you need these results to survive a refresh, then you will need to use local storeage

Additionally, it isnt recommended at all, but you could store it in the global window object.

Comment: Thanks James - Yep, I read somewhere else that $window was bad practise for this. Prepared for a quick fix, have you got a code example on how it could be done for this?